# R data frame dplyr separate_rows function on specific condition

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate

I have a data frame in long format, and I would like to separate the name column in separate rows using the delimiter comma, by the grade only equals to 12 and leave the rest.

df:

```
class   grade   name
english 12  peter,leo
english 10  henry,james
maths   12  leo
physics 12  mary,paul,chris
chemistry   12  jack
biology 12  ann
maths   10  thomas
physics 10  william,thomas
chemistry   8   sarah
biology 8   nancy,emma
chemistry   10  david,elizabeth
```

desired output:

```
class   grade   name
english 12  peter
english 12  leo
english 10  henry,james
maths   12  leo
physics 12  mary
physics 12  paul
physics 12  chris
chemistry   12  jack
biology 12  ann
maths   10  thomas
physics 10  william,thomas
chemistry   8   sarah
biology 8   nancy,emma
chemistry   10  david,elizabeth
```

I tried to do:

```
df %>% mutate(name=if_else(grade==12,separate_rows(name,sep = ","),name))
```

I got an error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `name = if_else(...)`.
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'separate_rows' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I can split into two data frames and combine them back together, it works but I don't know how to work in one line. Please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first `filter` the grade and `separate_rows` these rows and after that `bind_rows` the other back like this:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(grade == 12) %>%
  separate_rows(name, sep = ',') %>%
  bind_rows(., df %>% filter(grade != 12))
#> # A tibble: 14 × 3
#>    class     grade name           
#>    <chr>     <int> <chr>          
#>  1 english      12 peter          
#>  2 english      12 leo            
#>  3 maths        12 leo            
#>  4 physics      12 mary           
#>  5 physics      12 paul           
#>  6 physics      12 chris          
#>  7 chemistry    12 jack           
#>  8 biology      12 ann            
#>  9 english      10 henry,james    
#> 10 maths        10 thomas         
#> 11 physics      10 william,thomas 
#> 12 chemistry     8 sarah          
#> 13 biology       8 nancy,emma     
#> 14 chemistry    10 david,elizabeth
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>